# Flask restful - Exception handling traceback?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am using Flask Restful to build an API. I have a number of model classes with methods that may raise custom exceptions (for example: AuthFailed exception on my User model class). I am using the custom error handling, documented [here](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/extending.html#custom-error-handlers), to handle this (so that when auth fails, an appropriate response is sent). So far so good. However, I notice that when the exception is raised although the correct response JSON and status is sent back, I still get a traceback which is not ideal. Usually, if I handle an error (outside of flask) with a try-except block, the except can catch the error and handle it (preventing the traceback). So what is the correct approach here? Am I misunderstanding how to use the errors feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, it is handled this way "by design" of the Flask-RESTful APIs `errors` functionality.
The exceptions which are thrown are logged and the corresponding response defined in the `errors` dict is returned.

However, you can change the level of log output by modifying the log level of Flask's logger like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

I think you would actually have to set it to `CRITICAL` because these errors are still getting logged even on log level `ERROR` as far as I know.

Furthermore, both Flask and Flask-RESTful are open-source. That being said, after looking at the code I found [the function of a Flask app that is responsible for adding the exception traceback to the log](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.11.1/flask/app.py#L1576) (Flask version 0.11.1).
Of course you could just create your own `App` class (extending the original class of Flask) which overrides this method (or a caller of it) and does something else instead. However, you should be careful when updating your Flask version if you make use of undocumented stuff like this.

Comment: Hmm ok. Seems strange that there isn't a way to prevent errors from being logged (irrespective of error level) when they are being adequately handled! But oh well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't seen something else when working with Flask(-RESTful). However, I looked at the source code of Flask(-RESTful) again and found something that might help you out as well to achieve what you want to do (and to boost my answer to an acceptable level :P).